# Differentiation of functions w.r.t. a composed argument

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

I need help with the following derivative involving inner products: $$\frac{d\, \log(x)^T\,y}{d\,x^T\,y}$$
Here $x$ and $y$ are $n$-dimensional vectors, $T$ indicates transpose, and the logarithm of the vector is taken point-wise: $\log(x)_i = \log(x_i)$.

THANKS for your help in advance!!!

Comment: What is that $T$?

Comment: $T$ denotes transposed vector.

Comment: What is $\log x$ for the vector $x$? Is it the vector $(\log x_1, \log x_2, \ldots, \log x_n)$?

Comment: Since x is a vector, what are logx and ((log(x))^T*y?

Comment: $\log x=(log x_{1},...,log x_{n})$, so $((log(x))^T*y=\sum ((log x_{i})*y_{i})$.

Comment: If we forget about vectors, how can i calculate $\frac{d(\log(x)*y)}{d(x*y)}$?

Comment: @MathD May I ask where you found this problem?  Knowing the definitions is the first step in solving the problem, and the definitions depend on what you are trying to do.

Comment: This expression doesn't make sense as some sort of derivative. When the $x_i$ and the $y_i$ are $2n$ independent variables and $f$,  $g$ are two functions of these variables then it makes sense to consider the $1$-forms $df(x,y)$ and $dg(x,y)$, and one may then form the quotient of these. The latter is undefined on the kernel of $dg(x,y)$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Do you mean the statements from my answer? (Don't know whether the example calculation is correct. Don't have enough time to check thoroughly.)

Comment: Could you describe the origin of this problem? This would narrow down the possible interpretations of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question isn't undefined or ambiguous at all, it's just a lot of work.  Rewrite the given derivative into an equivalent expression with no derivatives except for the $n^2$ atomic expressions $\frac{d\,x_i}{d\,y_j}$ (see footnote)

$$\frac{d\,\sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i) y_i}{d\,\sum_{j=1}^n x_j y_j}$$

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n d\,\log(x_i) y_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n d\,x_j y_j}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{d\,\log(x_i) y_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n d\,x_j y_j}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n d\,x_j y_j}{d\,\log(x_i) y_i}\right)^{-1}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{ d\,x_j y_j}{d\,\log(x_i) y_i}\right)^{-1}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{ x_j\,d\,y_j + y_j\,d\,x_j}{\log(x_i)\,d\, y_i + y_i/x_i\,d\, x_i}\right)^{-1}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^n 
\frac{ x_j\,d\,y_j}{\log(x_i)\,d\, y_i + y_i/x_i\,d\, x_i}
+
\frac{y_j\,d\,x_j}{\log(x_i)\,d\, y_i + y_i/x_i\,d\, x_i}\right)^{-1}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^n 
\left(\frac{\log(x_i)\,d\, y_i + y_i/x_i\,d\, x_i}{ x_j\,d\,y_j}\right)^{-1}
+
\left(\frac{\log(x_i)\,d\, y_i + y_i/x_i\,d\, x_i}{y_j\,d\,x_j}\right)^{-1}
\right)^{-1}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^n 
\left(
\frac{\log(x_i)}{ x_j}\frac{d\, y_i}{d\,y_j}
  +
\frac{y_i/x_i}{ x_j}\frac{d\, x_i}{d\,y_j}
\right)^{-1}
+
\left(
\frac{\log(x_i)}{y_j}\frac{d\, y_i}{d\,x_j}
  +
\frac{y_i/x_i}{y_j}\frac{d\, x_i}{d\,x_j}
\right)^{-1}
\right)^{-1}$$

A special case of this (probably the one you are interested in) is where all of the variables are independent, that is:
$$(\forall i, j)\frac{d\,x_i}{d\,y_j} = 0$$
$$(\forall i \ne j)\frac{d\,x_i}{d\,x_j} = \frac{d\,y_i}{d\,y_j} = 0$$
$$(\forall i = j)\frac{d\,x_i}{d\,x_j} = \frac{d\,y_i}{d\,y_j} = 1$$

Edit: I believe the above derivation is only correct when the variables have a functional relationship, like $y = f(x)$.  When they are independent, it no longer seems to be correct, and I apologize, I haven't figured out how to solve the problem in that case yet.

---

Footnote:

Another way of thinking about the expression:  At any point in the logic, you should be able to apply an arbitrary set of consistent relationships between the variables and get a consistent result.  For example, consider if the poster had asked for the simpler expression:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d\,xy}{d\,x + y} &= \frac{xd\,y + yd\,x}{d\,x + d\,y}\\
&= \frac{x\,d\,y}{d\,x + d\,y} + \frac{y\,d\,x}{d\,x + d\,y}\\
&= \left(\frac{d\,x + d\,y}{x\,d\,y}\right)^{-1} + \left(\frac{d\,x + d\,y}{y\,d\,x}\right)^{-1}\\
&= \left(\frac{d\,x}{x\,d\,y} + \frac{d\,y}{x\,d\,y}\right)^{-1}
 + \left(\frac{d\,x}{y\,d\,x} + \frac{d\,y}{y\,d\,x}\right)^{-1}\\
&= x\left(\frac{d\,x}{d\,y} + 1\right)^{-1}
 + y\left(1 + \frac{d\,y}{d\,x}\right)^{-1}\\
\end{align}$$

Continuing the example, you are still free to add a new assumption, such as $y = e^{kx}$.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d\,xy}{d\,x + y} & = \frac{d\,xy}{d\,x} \left(\frac{d\,x + y}{d\,x}\right)^{-1}\\
&= \frac{d\,x\,e^{kx}}{d\,x} \left(\frac{d\,x + e^{kx}}{d\,x}\right)^{-1}\\
&=\frac{(k\,x\,+1)e^{kx}}{ke^{kx} + 1}
\end{align}$$

And applying the new assumption to the result:
$$\begin{align}
x\left(\frac{d\,x}{d\,y} + 1\right)^{-1}
 + y\left(1 + \frac{d\,y}{d\,x}\right)^{-1}
 & = x\left(k^{-1}e^{-kx} + 1\right)^{-1}
   + e^{kx}\left(1 + ke^{kx}\right)^{-1}\\
 & = x\left(\frac{ke^{kx}}{ke^{kx} + 1}\right) + e^{kx}\left(\frac{k^{-1}e^{-kx}}{k^{-1}e^{-kx} + 1}\right)\\
 & = kx\left(\frac{e^{kx}}{ke^{kx} + 1}\right) + e^{kx}\left(\frac{1}{1 + ke^{kx}}\right)\\
 & = \frac{(kx+1)e^{kx}}{ke^{kx} + 1}
\end{align}$$

Although this is only 1 example, it suggests that this sort of calculus is well defined and consistent.  It's just not the limited sort of calculus-of-functions that you see in schools.

Comment: As I have shown in my answer there is no solution to the original problem where you can choose the differentials independently. But, that depends on whether we have interpreted the original problem right. It is still an open question what the origin of the original problem of @MathD is.

Comment: @Tobias Although I can't follow your answer, I concur that this result is not correct when the variables are independent.  I'm still working on it because it is interesting to me.

Answer (score 0):

$(\log x)^T*y=\log(x_1^{y^1}.x_2^{y_2}.\ldots.x_n^{y_n})$ So you have to differentiate 
$x_1^{y_1}.x_2^{y_2}.\ldots.x_n^{y_n}$ with respect to $x_1y_1+x_2y_2+\ldots+x_ny_n$.

Comment: yes, but how can I differentiate $x^{y}$ w.r.t $xy$?

Answer (score 0):

$\def\nR{\mathbb{R}}\def\sign{\operatorname{sign}}\def\l{\left}\def\r{\right}\def\ltag#1{\tag{#1}\label{#1}}$
The only interpretation of the question I can think of is that you are given a vector of unknowns $z=[x,y]$ and two functions $f(z)=\log(x)^T\cdot y$ and $g(z)=x^T y$ and you should determine $a(z)$ such that
$$
\ltag{quest}
\frac{df(z)}{dg(z)} = a(z)
$$
where $df$ and $dg$ are to be interpreted as differentials. In this case you have
\begin{align}
df(z) &= a(z)\cdot dg(z)\\
f'(z)\cdot dz &= a(z)\cdot g'(z)\cdot dz\\
(f'(z)-a(z)g'(z))\cdot dz = 0
\end{align}
with $f'(z),g'(z)\in \nR^{1\times N}$. Note, that this equation is a generalized eigenvalue problem with $a(z)$ as the eigenvalue and $dz\in\nR^N$ as eigen direction.

In our case it is just a single equation which we can tackle directly.
\begin{align}
f'(z) &= \begin{pmatrix}
(y./x)^T,&\log(x)^T
\end{pmatrix}\\
g'(z) &= \begin{pmatrix}
y^T&x^T
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
We have to satisfy the equation
\begin{align}
\ltag{d}
((y./x)^T-a(z)\cdot y^T)\cdot dx + (\log(x)^T-a(z)\cdot x^T)\cdot dy &= 0
\end{align}
Let us assume the differentials $d x,dy$ were not restricted. Then the equations
\begin{align}
((y./x)^T-a(z)\cdot y^T)&=0\ltag{allDir1}\\
(\log(x)^T-a(z)\cdot x^T)&=0\ltag{allDir2}
\end{align}
would all have to be satisfied. The first component of equation \eqref{allDir1} reads as
$$
\ltag{a1}
a = \frac1{x_1}
$$
But, the other components of \eqref{allDir1} imply $x_k=\frac1{a}=x_1$ for $k=2,\ldots,n$ and the other equation \eqref{allDir2} says
\begin{align}
\ltag{a2}
a&=\frac{\log(x_k)}{x_k}&&\text{ for }k=1,\ldots,n.
\end{align}
Equations \eqref{a1} and \eqref{a2} are not solvable together.

Therfore, all solutions of equation \eqref{d} restrict the differential $dz$.

I think equation \eqref{quest} imposes further $g'(z)dz\neq 0$.
One could ask which differentials $dz$ and which values $a$ are admissible in this case.

For an instance the hyperplane $y=0$ is not admissible even if it looks good for \eqref{d}. It is not admissible since with $y=0$ we also have $dy=0$ and $g'(z)dz = y^Tdx + x^Tdy =0$.

Let us look at a hyperplane with $y=c$ for some fixed $c\neq 0\in\nR^n$.
Because of $dy=0$ we need $0\neq g'(z)dz=c^Tdx$.

In this case \eqref{d} gives the equation
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{c_k dx_k}{x_k}-ac_kdx_k = 0
\end{align}
Let us try $a=0$ and let us assume that just two components of $c_k$ are nonzero, e.g., $c_1=1$ and $c_2=-1$. We would end up with the equation
\begin{align}
\frac{dx_1}{x_1} = \frac{dx_2}{x_2}.
\end{align}

With the requirement $c_1\cdot dx_1 + c_2 \cdot dx_2\neq 0$ there would locally be at least one of the differentials $dx_1 , dx_2$ nonzero (the considered tangent vector to the manifold at hand would have a nonzero component in this direction). Integration yields
\begin{align}
\int_{x_{10}}^{x_1} \frac{d \bar x_1}{\bar x_1} &= \int_{x_{20}}^{x_2} \frac{d \bar x_2}{\bar x_2}\\
\log\l(\frac{x_1}{x_{10}}\r) &= \log\l(\frac{x_2}{x_{20}}\r)\\
\ltag{sur}
\frac{x_1}{x_{10}}  &= \frac{x_2}{x_{20}}
\end{align}
One case for an admissible solution is $a=0$ with a tangent vector $dz$ on plane hyper-surfaces with $y=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0&\ldots&0\end{pmatrix}^T$ satisfying equation \eqref{sur} and $x_1,x_2\neq 0$.

**This is not a complete characterization of the solution set of \eqref{quest}. But 1st it gives a reasonable interpretation of the question and 2nd gives some insight in the structure of the solution set of \eqref{quest}.**

---

Note, that differentials can be interpreted as components of tangent vectors as it is described in my answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92925/how-to-treat-differentials-and-infinitesimals/93025#93025.

Comment: @mathd: Note, somehow I got the dimensions wrong. We just have a single equation. That is much easier.